# How do I import javascripts libraries into my application with Ionic 2?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

How do I import javascripts libraries into my application with Ionic 2?

Some time ago I used Ionic 1 to develop hybrid applications, now I'm starting with Ionic 2, and from what I realized, it's only accepting npm's plugins. Example library I want to use: https://github.com/tsironis/lockr.

In Ionic 1 it was enough to import the script in the file index.html `(<script src = "/path/to/lockr.js" type = "text/javascript"> </ script>).`

Answer (score 1):

To bring in an external library, just install it via npm (be sure to use the `--save` parameter in case you blow away your node_modules folder at some point). Then all you need to do is add an `import` statement that references the module you want to include in any one of your files, and it will be brought in for you automatically.

Alternatively, you can still use `<script>` tags by editing the `index.html` file in the `www` directory of your project.

Comment: Exactly! Thank you very much! I've found on the Ionic 2 blog all the explanation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/third-party-libs/

Comment: @MarcosBatista Glad you got it worked out! If your problem is resolved, could you mark this answer as accepted?